# How and when did American spelling supersede British spelling in the US?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, history, dictionaries

Considering that Webster [published his first dictionary in 1806](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merriam-Webster), is there a recognised tipping point (year, decade, etc.) that marked the move from traditional British spelling to Webster's American? Was this shift a gradual but chaotic process or was it a deliberate and possibly collective decision taken by the educational institutions, the media, or the government of the time? In other words, how did the shift come about?

Comment: Superseding is not the right word. These things are gradual processes.

Comment: @Lambie So, _**overtake**_, then?

Comment: @Lambie why not _superseded_! Some things supersede gradually.

Comment: @NVZ  I just don't think spelling systems supersede (replace or supplant) each other. [subsede?? not a word, I shouldn't think]. Gradually is the key word for me. Gradually supercede, I'd accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the progress of [English spelling reform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform) (which is apparently the term of choice) in the United States generally appears to have been gradual and chaotic, three major periods of change through deliberate process seem to be its primary drivers.

Webster's first dictionary, *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language*, was published in 1806. He then spent twenty years revising it to produce the first [**American** Dictionary of the English Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster%27s_Dictionary#ADEL_first_edition_1828) (ADEL) which was published in 1828. An expanded and revised second edition appeared in 1841. *Although it drew some protest, the reformed spellings were gradually adopted throughout the United States.*

In [A History of English Spelling](http://books.google.com/books?id=pBkNAQAAIAAJ), D.G. Scragg [writes](http://books.google.com/books?id=pBkNAQAAIAAJ&q=1828#v=onepage&q=%22successful%20in%20establishing%20its%20authority%22&f=false):

> "But some remained, and since the book was successful in establishing its authority throughout the States, they have become generally recognized as American forms. In that sense Webster was the first to differentiate between British and American usage, and in that it was frequently he who chose the variant of two spellings in early nineteenth-century use which have subsequently been preferred in the United States, he can be said to have influenced the development of spelling. He is in a way 'responsible' for such forms as *center*, *color* and *defense*."

While Webster championed a number of spelling reforms, only a few were widely adopted.

The release and adoption of the ADEL editions certainly corroborates with a number of ngrams which show the new American spelling steadily becoming popular after the 1820s and eventually becoming more dominant on or after 1845. For example,

- 1841: [parlor > parlour](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parlour,%20parlor&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1846: [color > colour](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=color,%20colour&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1845: [rumor > rumour](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rumor,%20rumour&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1846: [honor > honour](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=honour,%20honor&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1843: [connection > connexion](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connection,%20connexion&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1844: [recognize > recognise](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recognise,%20recognize&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

There are a number of other similar instances. There are also examples such as [fraternize vs. fraternise](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fraternize,%20fraternise&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) where the former, while already (in terms of the ngram) maintaining a small lead in preference, takes a sudden leap after ~1835.

As mentioned earlier, only a few of Webster's reforms, of which many were contentious, were adopted. After his death, the more egregious of his changes were gradually dropped by subsequent editors. In the 1870s, the *American Spelling Reform Association* was formed. They, along with the *American Philological Society* and the *American Philological Association* worked further on simplifying (American) English spelling.

> That year, the American Philological Society adopted a list of eleven reformed spellings for immediate use. These were: *are→ar, give→giv, have→hav, live→liv, though→tho, through→thru, guard→gard, catalogue→catalog, (in)definite→(in)definit, wished→wisht*. **One major American newspaper that begun using reformed spellings was the Chicago Tribune**, whose editor and owner, Joseph Medill, sat on the Council of the Spelling Reform Association. In 1883, the American Philological Society and American Philological Association worked together to produce 24 spelling reform rules, which were published that year. In 1898, the **American National Education Association adopted its own list of 12 words to be used in all writings**. These were: *tho, altho, thoro, thorofare, thru, thruout, catalog, decalog, demagog, pedagog, prolog, program*.

We can see the effect of these reforms via a couple of ngrams:

- > 1880: [thru](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thru&year_start=1850&year_end=1980&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- > 1880: [demagog, decalog, prolog, epilog, pedagog](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demagog,decalog,prolog,epilog,pedagog&year_start=1800&year_end=1980&corpus=17&smoothing=30&share=)

1906 saw the formation of the [American Spelling Board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Spelling_Board) which was funded by Andrew Carnegie. They published a list of 300 words which were adopted by President Roosevelt for  government use.

> Roosevelt tried to force the federal government to adopt the system, sending an order to the Public Printer to use the system in all public federal documents. The order was obeyed; among the many documents printed using the system was the President's special message regarding the Panama Canal.
>
> However, in December 1906 the U.S. Congress passed a resolution and the old spellings were reintroduced. **Nevertheless, some of the spellings survived and are commonly used in American English today**, such as *anaemia/anæmia→anemia* and *mould→mold*. Others such as *mixed→mixt* and *scythe→sithe* did not survive.

The effect of *these* reforms can be seen in the following ngrams:

- 1906: [center > centre](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=centre,%20center&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1912: [defense > defence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defence,%20defense&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1912: [offense > offence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=offence,%20offense&year_start=1800&year_end=1930&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1910: [anemia > anaemia](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anaemia,%20anemia&year_start=1830&year_end=1980&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1913: [hydrolyze > hydrolyse](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hydrolyse,hydrolyze&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)
- 1912: [kilometer > kilometre](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kilometer,%20kilometre&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

To summarise, the divergence of American spelling is the result of spelling reforms initiated by Webster, taken further by interested parties including at least one media house, and eventually, the (temporary) backing of the US government. However, only a small percentage of each set of proposed reforms were adopted at any one time. The more drastic of reforms met with stiff resistance:

> Roosevelt ultimately decided to rescind the order. Brander Matthews, a friend of Roosevelt and one of the chief advocates of the reform as chairman of the Simplified Spelling Board, remonstrated with him for abandoning the effort. Roosevelt replied on December 16, 1906: "I could not by fighting have kept the new spelling in, and it was evidently worse than useless to go into an undignified contest when I was beaten. Do you know that the one word as to which I thought the new spelling was wrong — thru — was more responsible than anything else for our discomfiture?" Next summer Roosevelt was watching a naval review when a press boat marked "Pres Bot" chugged ostentatiously by. The President waved and laughed with delight.

Answer (score 55):

The answers to your questions are:

- Yes, the shift was and continues to be a gradual and chaotic process.
- No, there was not a a deliberate and possibly collective decision taken by the educational institutions, the media, or the government of the time.

Yes, there were a few changes that Webster tried, but the history of English spelling is much, much, much more complicated than that.  English has never had a single agreed-upon spelling, even within any one country.  There is no such thing as ***the*** American spelling, nor for that matter is there ***the*** British spelling, when discussing the English language.  At most, there are individual words that may show a general predilection, but that shifts over time and within writers and publishers.  It isn’t a simple us-vs-them situation almost in any pairing.  There is too much historical variation.

Here is a summary of my findings below sorted by year:

```
always  inflection, inflexion
always  paralyzed, paralysed
always  tire, tyre
1680    surprize, surprise
1770    surprise, surprize
1810    jewelry, jewellery
1835    colored, coloured
1835    deputize, deputise
1845    armor, armour
1845    connection, connexion
1905    aluminum, aluminium
1905    woolen, woollen
1910    esophagus, oesophagus
1910    fetus, foetus
1915    leveled, levelled
1920    center, centre
1930    savior, saviour
1940    miter, mitre
1940    specter, spectre
1970    acknowledgment, acknowledgement
1975    theater, theatre
1980    scepter, sceptre
never   ameba, amoeba
never   glamor, glamour
```

There is a lot more variation than even that summary shows; please see the more detailed charts below, including some that go the other way by showing British usage. Each of these really is a separate case, and must be considered individually.   There is no single, solitary, discrete, and agreed-upon thing called American spelling versus British spelling.  There is a vast continuum of conflicting tendencies, some weaving back and forth time across the Atlantic, and across time.   Even when one spelling “supersedes” another, it merely comes out ahead in the popularity contest.  It usually does not  wholly supplant the former spelling.

---

## For the Ngramaniacs

In all cases, the putative “American” spelling is in blue, and the putative “British” spelling is in red.  Notice how the answers are all over the board, and some rather surprising, too.

---

### *center* vs *centre*

When did *center* supersede *centre* in American English?  Answer: Around 1910. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=center%2Ccentre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)
[image]

### *theater* vs *theatre*

When did *theater* supersede *theatre* in American English.  Answer: During the late 1970s. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theater%2Ctheatre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *armor* vs *armour*

When did *armor* supersede *armour* in American English?  Answer: Around 1850. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=armor%2Carmour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *glamor* vs *glamour*

When did *glamor* supersede *glamour* in American English?  Answer: Never, because it has always been a minority usage.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glamor%2Cglamour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *woolen* vs *woollen*

When did *woolen* supersede *woollen* in American English?  Answer: around 1905. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=woolen%2Cwoollen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *tire* vs *tyre*

When did *tire* supersede *tyre* in American English? Answer: Never, because it was always dominant.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tire%2Ctyre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

Well, and when did *tyre* supersede *tire* in British English? Answer: in the early 1940s.  But it only lasted a couple of decades before falling back into minority usage again. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tire%2Ctyre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *miter* vs *mitre*

When did *miter* supersede *mitre* in American English? Answer: Around 1920.  Then again around 1940.  Then again around 1970.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miter%2Cmitre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *acknowledgment* vs *acknowledgement*

When did *acknowledgment* supersede *acknowledgement* in American English? Never. It has always been that way. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acknowledgment%2Cacknowledgement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

What about the other way around?  When did  *acknowledgement* supersede *acknowledgment* in British English?   Answer: Around 1970. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acknowledgment%2Cacknowledgement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *scepter* vs *sceptre*

When did *scepter* supersede *sceptre* in American English?  Answer: Around 1980.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scepter%2Csceptre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *savior* vs *saviour*

When did *savior* supersede *saviour* in American English?  Answer: Around 1930.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=savior%2Csaviour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *deputize* vs *deputise*

When did *deputize* supersede *deputise* in American English?  Answer: Around 1810.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deputize%2Cdeputise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

But what about the other way around?  When did *deputise* supersede *deputize* in British English?  It’s arguable, but the general answer is that it never did.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deputize%2Cdeputise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *ameba* vs *amoeba*

When did *ameba* supersede *amoeba* in American English?  Answer: Never. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ameba%2Camoeba&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *jewelry* vs *jewellery*

When did *jewelry* supersede *jewellery* in American English?  Answer: Around 1810.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jewelry%2Cjewellery&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *inflection* vs *inflexion*

When did *inflection* supersede *inflexion* in American English?  Answer: It probably never did, because it *inflection* was probably always the dominant spelling of that word in American publications.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inflexion%2Cinflection&year_start=1700&year_end=2020&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinflexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinflection%3B%2Cc0)

[image: inflexion vs inflection in American English]

The data from before 1800 is not of sufficiently high quality to use for drawing conclusions from.

But what about the other way around? When did *inflexion* supersede *inflection* in British English?  Answer: Mostly never.

Or, depending on the quality of the data, perhaps around 1805.  But if so, it only did so for 7 years, up through around 1812.  There was a minor and short-lived blip in the early 1920s when *inflexion* seems to have edged out *inflection* again in British English for a couple years tops, and then again between 1948–1962. Since then, the *inflexion* spelling has been on wane in British publication such that by 2000 the *inflection* spelling dominated the *inflexion* spelling by a factor of more than 5:1. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inflexion%2Cinflection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinflexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinflection%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

But what about the other way around? When did *connexion* supersede *connection* in British English?  Answer: Around 1820.  But it only did so for around 30 years, up through around 1850.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connection%2Cconnexion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *colored* vs *coloured*

Since this one seems to be everybody’s favorite peeve, when did *colored* supersede *coloured* in American English?  Answer: Around 1840.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colored%2Ccoloured&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *leveled* vs *levelled*

When did *leveled* supersede *levelled* in American English? Answer: Around 1915. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leveled%2Clevelled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *fetus* vs *foetus*

When did *fetus* supersede *foetus* in American English?  Answer: around 1910. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fetus%2Cfoetus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

Hm, but what about the other way around?  When did *foetus* supersede *fetus* in British English?  It didn’t: it gave up the lead around 1970.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fetus%2Cfoetus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *paralyzed* vs *paralysed*

When did *paralyzed* supersede *paralysed* in American English?  Answer: Always.  [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paralyzed%2Cparalysed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

And the other way around: when did *paralysed* supersede *paralyzed* in British English?  Answer, around 1830, but it has been losing a lot of ground recently.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paralyzed%2Cparalysed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *specter* vs *spectre*

When did *specter* supersede *spectre* in American English?  Answer: around 1940.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=specter%2Cspectre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)
[image]

### *esophagus* vs *oesophagus*

When did *esophagus* replace *oesophagus* in American English?  Answer: Around 1910.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=esophagus%2Coesophagus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

But what about British usage?  The answer is that *oesophagus* seems to have lost to *esophagus* around 1980, but then may have returned.  It’s hard to tell. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=esophagus%2Coesophagus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *aluminum* vs *aluminium*

When did *aluminum* supersede *aluminium* in American English?  Answer: around 1900.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aluminum%2Caluminium&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

And what about the other way around?  When did *aluminium* supersede *aluminum* in British English?  Answer: around 1850, but it has lost a great deal of ground of late.  [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aluminum%2Caluminium&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

### *surprize* vs *surprise*

It turns out that *surprize* was once the dominant form, not *surprise*, but this didn’t last even a hundred years. [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprize%2Csurprise&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=)

[image]

Then again, here is the [British Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprize%2Csurprise&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=) for the same pair. Notice that even the Brits used the *z* for a good while, possibly even for longer than in North America:

[image]

---

## Summary

I hope you can now see why I said what I said: that there can be no clear answer here.  Everything is different.  You have to look at each word-pair separately, and you should make sure you aren’t wrong about Britain, either.

Comment: Yet there *are* characteristics of American spelling vs. English spelling; for example, color vs. colour. How did that difference come about?

Comment: @Marthaª That is just one particular instance of a great many changes, and that is not the question asked, either. Even if you constrain yourself to hackneyed stereotypes, you’ll find serious surprises in things like *deputize/deputise* or *savior/saviour*.

Comment: Yet, if you look at the ngrams of "hackneyed stereotypes" such as colour, sceptic, flavour and rumour, their American spelling equivalents all take root after Webster's dictionaries were published and many of them supplant their British antecedents at roughly the same time. The fact that some words or changes have their own history does not belie the fact that there is an American standard or that there appears to have been a conscious push to adopt the advertised standard of the time. I'm not sure which of my assumptions you consider false; please explain.

Comment: @tchrist I think many of the trends you mention are examples of words being taken over from other cultures, loanwords. And maybe the differences will be getting smaller and smaller in the future. But that doesn't explain where the differences came from in the first place.

Comment: @tchrist: on the contrary, I think that is *exactly* the question being asked. The details might be wrong — that's why he's asking, after all — but there seems to have been a process by which American spelling diverged from British spelling. The presence of outliers, iconoclasts, and immigrants doesn't change this fact.

Comment: The OP is certainly not the first to suggest that there are many words that Americans spell differently than Britons: this is generally taken as common knowledge and not some radical new theory. Are you seriously saying that this is not true? Yes, yes, you can find cases where an American used the British spelling and vice versa, but that hardly refutes the theory. (Just as it is true that men are generally taller than women, even though there are cases of women who are taller than the average man.) Indeed, the very fact that when I say, "An American used the British spelling of 'colour'" ...

Comment: ... almost every reader instantly knows that the American spelling is 'color', no? How many would really say, "Wait, so how did the American spell it?"

Comment: @Jay You really do have to look at each word.  Do you really expect people to post dozens of dodgy Google N-Grams?  I looked at a few, and it really does vary a lot.

Comment: @coleopterist You assume that everything changed at the same time.  You also assume that it is American spelling which changed while pristine British spelling remained inviolated.  Neither of those is true. You can run Ngrams as well as anybody.  Note however that it misattributes many writers to the wrong corpus.

Comment: @Marthaª I beg you to reconsider.  Look at the data.

Comment: +1 Should we really go to such lengths on a Q&A site like ELU?

Comment: @tchrist If I assumed that everything changed at the same time, would I ask in my question if the shift was gradual and chaotic? I'm afraid that you have somehow jumped to the conclusion that I'm trying to insinuate that British spelling is better than American spelling or something along those lines. This and the haphazardness of the choices made for the ngrams have tainted what could have otherwise been an interesting answer.

Comment: @tchrist I honestly and seriously don't understand why you're making up all these "you assume" statements. It undermines the whole point of your answer.

Comment: @coleopterist I have no idea what you are are talking about. "Haphazardness"?  If you had a particular word in mind, you should have asked about it. I have shown that the changes have happened at different times in different places to different words. I don’t know what else you are looking for. There was no single statement by the American Academy of the Language that suddenly changed things.

Comment: @MrLister If you have a better answer, pray provide it. I am not making up any "you assume" statements whatsoever.  Please read my answer.

Comment: *Tire* in Britain is almost always related to weariness: cars have tyres. I don't think that weakens your answer (with which I largely agree), but it does weaken the belief that Ngrams are helpful in such cases.

Comment: As @TimLymington points out: be careful with “tire” (“fatigue” is one synonym). Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: While many of the Ngrams illustrate a more gradual increase of American spellings and not a complete overtaking until later - There does seem to be a pattern for many words losing popularity and then gaining momentum again about 1830. I think that is kind of interesting. {center, armor, savior, connection, colored}, arguably {jewelry, deputise}

Comment: This might be due to the release of **American Dictionary of the English Language** as [coleopterist's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88379/60910) mentions - since I just read his answer.

Comment: I knew it was your post before I saw the final proof.

Comment: @TimLymington You can append `_NOUN` to restrict by part of speech: [tires vs tyres (noun)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tires_NOUN%2Ctyres_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctires_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctyres_NOUN%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: +1 and I had to scroll down forever to reach the bottom of this. :)

Answer (score 12):

One needs to understand that a lot of this has to do with the advancing tide of universal public education in the US.  Some public schools were developed in the mid to late 1700s (Benjamin Franklin had a hand in starting one), but the movement really gained steam in the early 1800s.  (Horace Mann was a well-known advocate, and, as a result, has nearly as many schools named after him as Washington or Lincoln.)  Education came to be seen as not only a legitimate concern of state and local governments, but in many cases one of the most important aspects.

The resulting explosion in public schools, especially at the elementary level, was so vast (as was the westward migration of the population) that most school teachers had an eighth-grade education, often considerably less.  As a result they relied on what was essentially a prescriptivist approach of teaching spelling and pronunciation from a relatively small number of texts, with Webster's dictionary being a major contributor.

Simultaneously, students from many backgrounds, many knowing no English at all (their parents having recently emigrated from Norway or Italy or Germany, for example), were thrown into these schools.  Parents, teachers, and the general public saw this as an opportunity to teach children the "right" way to speak English, and so the teachers were even more motivated to rely on Webster's dictionary to achieve a "universal" result.

Certainly this progress was "chaotic" (universal primary education took a full century to spread across the whole country, for example), but the progress was steady and strongly motivated.  (The "motivation" occurred at all levels — local, state, and federal.  While no one loved taxes even back then, most people saw the merits of public education and were, for the most part, willing to contribute their fair share.)

But the result of this is that Americans, in spite of their diverse backgrounds and the wide distances between many population centers, speak/spell a relatively standardized language.  This is especially the case when one gets away from the East Coast (whose populations predate the universal education movement).

Comment: Also regarding public education, I believe something should be said about budgets. One of the reasons Webster's dictionary became particularly popular is since after shortly after Merriam Co. took over, they significantly reduced the price just to increase sales. In 1847 they lowered the price from $15 to $6, making it very affordable to schools, which alongside some critical acclaim among senators and presidents, led New York and Massachusetts to buy many copies for their schools. [At least, that's gist of the story as Merriam-Webster tells it.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/legacy.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Oesophagus has always been spelt that way in Britain. If spelt correctly, Tyre and tire are two entirely different words, as has already been pointed out. I have never seen foetus spelt as fetus in the UK. Paralysed is always the correct spelling here and aluminium is always aluminium.

I am a bit puzzled about where some of the data on 'British English' is coming from, as it is very suspect.

Comment: This is interesting extra information about instances of British spelling, but does not address the OP's question and would be better as a comment there.

Comment: Don't forget the original spelling was aluminum and BrE inserted the 'i' later.

Comment: My shooting-from-the-hip hypothesis is that the corpus of supposedly British English is skewed by the fact that it is taken from prominent print sources, and prominent print sources are more likely to try to use spelling that they believe will accommodate the widest possible audience.  Thus it may in fact be a corpus of semi-"international" English.  The way British people naturally write on a daily basis when not filtered by editors and those with a market-driven agenda—which the corpus most likely does not include—would be much more useful data to have.