# When did Americans begin to use “practice” instead of “practise”?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, history, transatlantic-differences

I am writing an historical novel, and I try to have my characters speaking and writing as everybody did at the time. But I don't know when we in the US began to use *practice* as a verb instead of *practise*.

Could you give me an approximate date?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practise%2Cpractice&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpractice%3B%2Cc0

Comment: They certainly never began saying “when do Americans began”. The correct phrase is “when did Americans begin”. Truth be told, if you are not sure at this level of English grammar, I would advise against trying too hard to emulate earlier stages of the language.

Comment: Well, since there's no difference in pronunciation between _practice_ and _practise_ -- the difference is strictly in the spelling of the word, not in the word itself -- in dialogue you can spell it any way you like. As for when spelling conventions changed, that probably took a long time and happened at different rates in different groups of writers and readers and teachers.

Comment: @Jim https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practise_VERB%2Cpractice_VERB&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractise_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpractice_VERB%3B%2Cc0 gives quite different results.

Comment: @JonHanna- That's pretty interesting.

Comment: You’re asking the question the wrong way around.

Comment: @John Lawler 'Well, since there's no difference in pronunciation ... the difference is strictly in the spelling of the word, not in the word itself -- in dialogue you can spell it any way you like.' So the manner of physical recording is (if faithful to the spoken word) largely irrelevant.  I'll try that on my wife Catherine next time she insists on going over to Dublin and queuing for two hours to get to see another two pages of the Book of Kells. I predict that my ability to type will be affected.

Comment: Understand that English spelling was largely ad hoc until the late 1400s, when the printing press made it desirable to develop some standards (and also made dictionaries practical).  Until that time "practice" might have been spelled five different ways, and it took 200 years or so for spelling to fully "harden", by which time the New World had already been colonized.  This left many segments of the culture with multiple spellings (and perhaps odd "rules" for when to use which).  In the US Noah Webster's dictionary "settled" the issue.

Comment: @tchrist No one seems to care to notice, including the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and when did American spelling supersede British spelling in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87978/how-and-when-did-american-spelling-supersede-british-spelling-in-the-us)

Answer (score 3):

Samuel Johnson, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1756) spells the verb *practise* and the noun *practice*. Johnson also includes entries for the related noun forms *practisant*, *practiser*, and *practitioner*.

Noah Webster, *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806) spells both the verb and the noun *practice*, and includes entries for the related nouns *practicer*, *practisant*, and *practitioner*. So what did Webster think he was accomplishing by changing the verb *practise* and the noun *practiser* to *practice* and *practicer* while leaving the other words alone?

The answer is that Webster was trying to uphold several not entirely compatible principles of language, each having a different force. The most basic principle, you might reasonably suppose, was that of uniformity. In his preface to the *Compendious Dictionary*, Webster says this:

> Nor ought this principle of uniformity to be violated; for uniformity in the classes of words is the most convenient principle in the structure of language, and whatever arbitrary rules the learned may frame, the greatest part of men will be governed by habits of uniformity. To these habits we are indebted for all the regularity which is found in our own language or in any other.
>
> For this reason, rather than from a rigid adherence to the originals, we ought to write defense, pretense, offense, recompense, &c. with *s* instead of *c*; for we always use that letter in the derivatives, defensive, offensive, pretension, recompensing.

But uniformity across a class of words is a far less monolithic principle than you might suppose. Though Webster wanted to convert *defence* to *defense*, *offence* to *offense*, *pretence* to *pretense*, and *recompence* to *recompense*, he showed no similar interest with regard to *difference*, *eminence*, *preference*, and *sequence*.

And though he rejected separate spellings for *practice* (noun) and *practise* (verb), he didn't try to force *practitioner* to become *practicioner*. The reason he accepted the non-uniformity of *practitioner* and *practisant* in the midst of an attempt to unify the spelling of *practice*, I suspect, is that he was actually rather conservative on the question of sweeping away old spellings that could claim to reflect accurately the historical development of a word family.

One might wonder, for example, why Webster was inclined to change the verb to *practice* rather than choosing to change the noun to *practise*. Here I think, his regard for etymology played a major role, as he cited the Spanish *practica*, the Italian *pratica*, the French *pratique*, and the Greek πραχτιχη (along with πρασσω and πραττω, admittedly) in the 1828 *American Dictionary of the English Language*. But in the 1828 dictionary, he also made an argument for *practice* as the spelling of the verb by analogy to *notice*:

> PRACTICE v.t. {From the noun. The orthography of the verb ought to be the same as of the noun; as in *notice* and *to notice*.}

Interestingly, Johnson's 1756 Dictionary has an entry for *notice* as a noun but no entry under any spelling for the verb form.

Webster may also have been influenced in favor of the spelling *practice* by his view of the influence of Norman French on Saxon English after the Conquest. Again from the preface to the 1806 Compendious Dictionary:

> The Norman conquest however effected a change in the power of *c*, and established it as the equivalent of *s* before *e*, *i*, and *y*.

It would follow (under Webster's analysis) that the Norman influence gave English *practice* with an *s* sound but could not support *practicant* with an *s* sound, meaning that the spelling of that word had to be *practisant*.

---

***Conclusion***

In any event, the American adoption of the spelling *practice* for the verb that was spelled *practise* in England is directly attributable to Noah Webster, who made *practice* the only spelling that his dictionaries listed throughout the nineteenth century, starting with his first dictionary, the 1806 *Compendious Dictionary of the English Language*.

Underscoring Webster's responsibility for the U.S. adoption of *practice* as the spelling of the verb is the fact that his one real rival in the American dictionary trade, Joseph Worcester, consistently listed *practise* (not *practice*) as the spelling of the verb form of the word, and *practiser* (not *practicer*) as the derivative noun—for example, in *A Comprehensive Pronouncing and Explanatory Dictionary of the English Language*, revised edition (1845), and in *A Comprehensive Pronouncing and Explanatory Dictionary of the English Language*, [further] revised edition (1871).

Thanks to the dictionary war between Webster and Worcester, an American might spell the verb *practice* as early as 1806 with the blessing of Webster, or spell the verb *practise* at least as late as 1871 with the blessing of Worcester's executors.

Answer (score 1):

**Practice** appears in [both the 1913 and 1828 versions](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=practice&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search) of Webster's unabridged dictionary, so that spelling was in use before 1828.
**Practise** only appears [in the 1913 version](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=practise&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on).

Comment: But isn't that because Noah Webster decided to change the spelling of the verb from *practise* to *practice*? (The noun has always been *practice*.) Was that what people actually used? Not according to this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practicing%2Cpractising&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpracticing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpractising%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Could be. There's clearly a disharmony between the two sources.

Comment: As Peter mentions, this was quite possibly due to Noah Webster himself, who was into [spelling reform](http://www.bartleby.com/185/32.html), and is single-handedly responsible for a lot of the differences in US/UK spelling.