# “Councilor” vs. “Councillor”

Tags: word-usage, orthography, transatlantic-differences

Is *councilor* the spelling used in the U.S., while *councillor* the spelling used in Canada, UK, and most places internationally?

Hilariously, Google will use both *councilor* and *councillor* in the same definition.

[image: Google is not a citable reference]

Comment: I don't think Google is doing anything hilarious. It's merely listing the variant, like it does for *color/colour*: https://www.google.com/#q=colour

Answer (score 3):

First, *councilor* and *councillor* are exactly the same word under two variant spellings, just like the names *John* and *Jon*.

Second, it is not true that *councilor* “is the US spelling”. In point of fact, *councillor* is fully **twice as common** in print in the United States as *councilor* is according to this [Google n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=councilor%2Ccouncillor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouncilor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouncillor%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram of councillor vs. councilor (sic) in World English]

Across the broader anglosphere at large, the longer spelling dominates the shorter one by a factor of [more than four and a half to one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=councilor%2Ccouncillor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouncilor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouncillor%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram of councillor vs. councilor (sic) in American English]

While in Britain, use of the short spelling is so rare [at fifty to one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=councilor%2Ccouncillor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouncilor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouncillor%3B%2Cc0) that it would not surprised me if those scant few occurrences weren’t  considered an error there:

[image: ngram of councillor vs. councilor (sic) in British English]

## The Moral of the Story

Do not believe everything that you’re told by meddlesome spellchecking software or even by newspaper editors: fully two thirds of American uses in the studied corpus are still the longer version.

That’s because there is no shortage of living American writers who, being from a generation that was never taught to trust programs before themselves, continue to spell such words as they were first taught to, not how some unscholarly <s>programer</s> programmer from some monopolistic leviathan *thought* they should spell things.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87978/how-and-when-did-american-spelling-supersede-british-spelling-in-the-us/87985#87985).

Comment: ' not how some unscholarly programer programmer from some monopolistic leviathan thought they should spell things' ... echoes of Webster?

Answer (score 1):

You consulted the US Google, so it shows the US spelling in large letters, then the alternate spelling(s) below.   Other examples:

[image: artifact]

[image: colour]

[image: programme]

Comment: Remembering that “Google” does not count as a citable published reference, we’re now down to debating how some random bit of software behaves, not studying actual usage.